# Has the connection between these characters and this event been confirmed in Agents of SHIELD (so far)?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, agents-of-shield

In the end stinger from S6E6 ("Inescapable"), Mack seems to suggest that

> Sarge and Co. are responsible for the destruction of the Chronicom homeworld.

Not that I'm doubting it - it's just enough of a plot convenience to be true - but has any of the exposition we've seen so far explicitly confirmed this?

Comment: No. Why don't you just wait a few episodes to find out?

Comment: Interestingly everyone assumed it was true although neither Sarge nor Izel ever explicitly confirmed it. Though it makes sense given what she was looking for.